# In Twig, how can I check if an array has 0-based sequential numeric keys?

Tags: arrays, twig

I have an `array` variable in Twig that can either hold an array with string keys or an array with *0-based sequential numeric keys*. For the string keys I want to display it as `<key>: <value>`, but for the numeric keys I want to display it as `- <value>`:

```
{% set is_sequential = <check keys of array> %}
<ul>
    {% for k, v in array %}
        <li>{{ (is_sequential ? '- ' : k ~ ': ') ~ v }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

What could be the check at `<check keys of array>` in `{% set is_sequential = <check keys of array> %}`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if an array has *0-based sequential numeric keys* you could compare the keys of the array against the keys of an array created with the `range()` function:

If you have an `array` containing `['a','b','c','d']` then `array|keys|join(',')` will give the string `0,1,2,3`. Now you can compare that string to the output of `range(0, array|length - 1)|join(',')`, which will also produce the string `0,1,2,3`:

Thus:

```
{% set is_sequential = array|keys|join(',') is same as(range(0, array|length - 1)|join(',')) %}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it better to move this to a [custom test](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/advanced.html#tests) than do it inside the template?

Comment: I don't know if this would be better, but that's definitely also a good option.

Comment: With better I mean, if you would need this snippet on more than one place